# Python: How can I remove addons from my custom node tree?

Tags: python, node-editor

I have a custom node tree that I created. Currently, all of the addons that have menus in the node editor show up when I use my custom tree. Is there a way that I can remove them? They do not work with my tree and make it harder for my users to understand what is going on.

[image: other node helpers in my tree]

On my other computer, I have more addons then just this one that show up in the node editor.

Comment: I updated with a picture and a better desc.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, I had the same problem with Animation Nodes. The only solution seems to be that someone creates a patch for the other addon that only displays it in specific node tree types. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I've submitted a patch for *Node Wrangler*: https://developer.blender.org/D2262.